# fcase() gives error: "Error: C stack usage 15923072 is too close to the limit"

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to manipulate dataset using data.table. There are several conditions that needs to be met for one column, so I tried to incorporate fcase() in the code, but it gives me error:

"Error: C stack usage  15923072 is too close to the limit"

Maybe you could help me to figure out the cause of it?

Here's the code that I'm trying to run:

```
minind <- function (x) 
{
    min(which(!is.na(x)))
}

unemployment <- as.data.table(unemployment) %>% 
  .[, Date := quarters.frame.extended$num[match(Year, quarters.frame.extended$char)]] %>%
  .[order(Country, Date)] %>% 
  .[, Date := NULL] %>%
  .[, Year := as.character(Year)] %>% 
  .[, last.value := ifelse(is.na(last.value), last.value.gdp, last.value), by = .(Country, Year)] %>% 
  .[, last.year.position := which(Year == last.value),  by = Country] %>% 
  .[,c("Real GDP Growth", "last.value.gdp", "ProductName") := NULL] %>%
  .[,  id := minind(hist.unempl), by = .(Country)] %>%
  .[, data.int := fcase(all(is.na(hist.unempl)), data.int,
                        .I < minind(hist.unempl), NA,
                        !is.na(hist.unempl), hist.unempl),
                        by = .(Country)]
```

For clarification, minind() is a custom made function that returns the index of the first non-NA value of a vector.

Also, here is dput() output for reproducability

```
unemployment <- structure(list(Country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
                                 "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
                                 "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
                                 "Argentina", "Argentina"),
                     Year = c("Y2000M12", "Y2000M3", "Y2000M6", "Y2000M9", "Y2001M12", "Y2001M3", 
                              "Y2001M6", "Y2001M9", "Y2002M12", "Y2002M3", "Y2002M6", "Y2002M9", 
                              "Y2003M12", "Y2003M3", "Y2003M6"), 
                     rgdp = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                              NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                     prev.forecast.un = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.57, 19.44, 17.21), 
                     hist.unempl = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.5706780283859, 
                     19.4389142421615, 17.2096003722199), 
                     last.value = c("Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", 
                     "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3", "Y2022M3"), 
                     ProductName = c(NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                     NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
                     NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
                     target.q = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
                                  NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                     data.int = c(15.6761907862794, 14.5483085867427, 14.7959232297143, 
                     15.1715773972637, 18.4457204716021, 16.2695261753496, 16.9697699142562, 
                     17.726983438792, 19.2921646607513, 19.5604070253303, 19.8502473161049, 
                     19.7491809978135, 15.8261934880315, 18.6330789019461, 17.7486678920244), 
                     `Real GDP Growth` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                           NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,
                                           NA_real_), 
                     last.value.gdp = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
                                        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
                                        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

quarters.frame.extended <- structure(list(char = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 17L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 21L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 33L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 37L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 41L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 45L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 49L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 53L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
57L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 61L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 65L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 69L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 73L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 77L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 81L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 85L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 89L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 93L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 97L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 101L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 105L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 109L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 113L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 117L, 
122L, 123L, 124L, 121L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 125L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 
129L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 133L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 137L, 142L, 143L, 
144L, 141L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 145L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 149L, 154L, 
155L, 156L, 153L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 157L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 161L
), .Label = c("Y2000M12", "Y2000M3", "Y2000M6", "Y2000M9", "Y2001M12", 
"Y2001M3", "Y2001M6", "Y2001M9", "Y2002M12", "Y2002M3", "Y2002M6", 
"Y2002M9", "Y2003M12", "Y2003M3", "Y2003M6", "Y2003M9", "Y2004M12", 
"Y2004M3", "Y2004M6", "Y2004M9", "Y2005M12", "Y2005M3", "Y2005M6", 
"Y2005M9", "Y2006M12", "Y2006M3", "Y2006M6", "Y2006M9", "Y2007M12", 
"Y2007M3", "Y2007M6", "Y2007M9", "Y2008M12", "Y2008M3", "Y2008M6", 
"Y2008M9", "Y2009M12", "Y2009M3", "Y2009M6", "Y2009M9", "Y2010M12", 
"Y2010M3", "Y2010M6", "Y2010M9", "Y2011M12", "Y2011M3", "Y2011M6", 
"Y2011M9", "Y2012M12", "Y2012M3", "Y2012M6", "Y2012M9", "Y2013M12", 
"Y2013M3", "Y2013M6", "Y2013M9", "Y2014M12", "Y2014M3", "Y2014M6", 
"Y2014M9", "Y2015M12", "Y2015M3", "Y2015M6", "Y2015M9", "Y2016M12", 
"Y2016M3", "Y2016M6", "Y2016M9", "Y2017M12", "Y2017M3", "Y2017M6", 
"Y2017M9", "Y2018M12", "Y2018M3", "Y2018M6", "Y2018M9", "Y2019M12", 
"Y2019M3", "Y2019M6", "Y2019M9", "Y2020M12", "Y2020M3", "Y2020M6", 
"Y2020M9", "Y2021M12", "Y2021M3", "Y2021M6", "Y2021M9", "Y2022M12", 
"Y2022M3", "Y2022M6", "Y2022M9", "Y2023M12", "Y2023M3", "Y2023M6", 
"Y2023M9", "Y2024M12", "Y2024M3", "Y2024M6", "Y2024M9", "Y2025M12", 
"Y2025M3", "Y2025M6", "Y2025M9", "Y2026M12", "Y2026M3", "Y2026M6", 
"Y2026M9", "Y2027M12", "Y2027M3", "Y2027M6", "Y2027M9", "Y2028M12", 
"Y2028M3", "Y2028M6", "Y2028M9", "Y2029M12", "Y2029M3", "Y2029M6", 
"Y2029M9", "Y2030M12", "Y2030M3", "Y2030M6", "Y2030M9", "Y2031M12", 
"Y2031M3", "Y2031M6", "Y2031M9", "Y2032M12", "Y2032M3", "Y2032M6", 
"Y2032M9", "Y2033M12", "Y2033M3", "Y2033M6", "Y2033M9", "Y2034M12", 
"Y2034M3", "Y2034M6", "Y2034M9", "Y2035M12", "Y2035M3", "Y2035M6", 
"Y2035M9", "Y2036M12", "Y2036M3", "Y2036M6", "Y2036M9", "Y2037M12", 
"Y2037M3", "Y2037M6", "Y2037M9", "Y2038M12", "Y2038M3", "Y2038M6", 
"Y2038M9", "Y2039M12", "Y2039M3", "Y2039M6", "Y2039M9", "Y2040M12", 
"Y2040M3", "Y2040M6", "Y2040M9"), class = "factor"), num = c(2000.25, 
2000.5, 2000.75, 2001, 2001.25, 2001.5, 2001.75, 2002, 2002.25, 
2002.5, 2002.75, 2003, 2003.25, 2003.5, 2003.75, 2004, 2004.25, 
2004.5, 2004.75, 2005, 2005.25, 2005.5, 2005.75, 2006, 2006.25, 
2006.5, 2006.75, 2007, 2007.25, 2007.5, 2007.75, 2008, 2008.25, 
2008.5, 2008.75, 2009, 2009.25, 2009.5, 2009.75, 2010, 2010.25, 
2010.5, 2010.75, 2011, 2011.25, 2011.5, 2011.75, 2012, 2012.25, 
2012.5, 2012.75, 2013, 2013.25, 2013.5, 2013.75, 2014, 2014.25, 
2014.5, 2014.75, 2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2016, 2016.25, 
2016.5, 2016.75, 2017, 2017.25, 2017.5, 2017.75, 2018, 2018.25, 
2018.5, 2018.75, 2019, 2019.25, 2019.5, 2019.75, 2020, 2020.25, 
2020.5, 2020.75, 2021, 2021.25, 2021.5, 2021.75, 2022, 2022.25, 
2022.5, 2022.75, 2023, 2023.25, 2023.5, 2023.75, 2024, 2024.25, 
2024.5, 2024.75, 2025, 2025.25, 2025.5, 2025.75, 2026, 2026.25, 
2026.5, 2026.75, 2027, 2027.25, 2027.5, 2027.75, 2028, 2028.25, 
2028.5, 2028.75, 2029, 2029.25, 2029.5, 2029.75, 2030, 2030.25, 
2030.5, 2030.75, 2031, 2031.25, 2031.5, 2031.75, 2032, 2032.25, 
2032.5, 2032.75, 2033, 2033.25, 2033.5, 2033.75, 2034, 2034.25, 
2034.5, 2034.75, 2035, 2035.25, 2035.5, 2035.75, 2036, 2036.25, 
2036.5, 2036.75, 2037, 2037.25, 2037.5, 2037.75, 2038, 2038.25, 
2038.5, 2038.75, 2039, 2039.25, 2039.5, 2039.75, 2040, 2040.25, 
2040.5, 2040.75, 2041)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-164L))
```

Comment: For reprodutibility, add a sample of your data usind dput(head(unemployment, 10)), also from which package did the minind() function comes from (or is ir custom made)?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I made updates to my original question where I also added dput() output and clarified minind().

Comment: Please include `quarters.frame.extended` as well.

Comment: Make your example minimal by removing pkgs that are not necessary to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

As I try to understand what you need, I arrive at this:

```
minind <- function(x){
  which.min(is.na(x))
}

unemployment2 <- as.data.table(unemployment) %>% 
  .[, Date := quarters.frame.extended$num[match(Year, quarters.frame.extended$char)]] %>%
  .[order(Country, Date)] %>% 
  .[, Date := NULL] %>%
  .[, Year := as.character(Year)] %>% 
  .[, last.value := fifelse(is.na(last.value), last.value.gdp, last.value), by = .(Country, Year)] %>% 
  .[, last.year.position := which(Year == last.value),  by = Country] %>% 
  .[,c("Real GDP Growth", "last.value.gdp", "ProductName") := NULL] %>%
  .[,  id := minind(hist.unempl), by = .(Country)] %>%
  .[, index := .I, by = .(Country)] %>% 
  .[index < id, data.int := NA_real_] %>% 
  .[!is.na(hist.unempl), data.int := hist.unempl]
```